# Как расшифровать пароль в обновлённом Yandex браузере?

Tags: c#, sqlite

В Yandex'e обновили базу SQlite, и теперь просто так её не расшифровать. Подскажите есть ли новый способ расшифровки данных или нет?

При попытке расшифровать данным способом:

```
var decrypted = ProtectedData.Unprotect((byte[])reader["password_value"],
null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

получаю оишбку:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Параметр задан
>   неверно

Извлекаю данные через `System.Data.SQLite;`

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      var Url = reader.GetString(0);
      var Login = reader.GetString(1);
      try
      {
        var decrypted = 
        ProtectedData.Unprotect((byte[])reader["password_value"], null, 
        DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        var pw = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(pw);
      }
   }
}
```

Я так полагаю там новый способ шифрования файлов, и теперь просто так не расшифровать?
Теперь файл называется не `Login Data` а `Ya Login Data`

Comment: @Bulson, Это же вроде стандарт класс из `Cryptography`, а Вы попробуйте добавить `using System.Security.Cryptography;`

Comment: Да, действительно, извините, был неправ.

Comment: @Bulson, Всё нормально, с кем не бывает, но всё таки пока решения не нашёл :(

Comment: Я так понял на данный вопрос, ответа мне не дадут =)

Comment: "Я так полагаю там новый способ шифрования файлов,..." - эту догадку вы можете сами проверить. Открыть файл базы, допустим, в `SQLite Studio` и посмотреть значение поля, в котором хранится, известный вам заранее, зашифрованный пароль, с тем значением, которое вы можете получить с помощью `ProtectedData`.

Comment: @Bulson, Хорошо попробую, но это не догадки а так и есть, например для остальных файлов по типу `Login Data` всё читается нормально. А вот с новым файлом нет. Я конечно буду сам что-то искать и предпринимать, но всё же хотелось бы какой-нибудь помощи со стороны)

Comment: Ваша задача, скажем так, немного специфическая, с неясными мотивами. Мне, допустим, как хозяину своих паролей будет не очень комфортно осознавать, что кто-то может запустить свою программу под моим аккаунтом и узнать все мои пароли от разных интернет-ресурсов. Поэтому я даже приветствую тот возможный факт, что яндексойды изменили алгоритм шифрования и будут сохранять его в тайне от слишком любознательных любителей темных делишек.

Comment: @Bulson, Всё ясно, такой ответ я и ожидал в принципе услышать!